# Join PySpark SQL DataFrames that are already partitioned in a subset of the keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join 2 Spark DataFrames that is already partitioned in a subset of the keys I use to join. But when I do it, *Exchange* operations still occur anyway. How can I join them without *Exchange* or *Broadcast*.

For example, I have DataFrame *df1* and *df2*. They both have the same columns that are *col1*, *col2*, *col3*. And they both have already been partitioned using *col1*. I want to join them using *col1* and *col2*. But when I do it, It get repartitioned again using *col1* and *col2*.

Comment: can you partition by both col1 and col2?

Comment: @mck The data is already in the partition of col1 so I don't what to shuffle it.

Comment: Another good reason: what if col1 is high cardinality, col2 and col3 are low cardinality and you get limited benefit out of shuffling in terms of splitting up the data into partitions

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK,the dataframe needs to be partitioned by same column on both sides, for one shuffle.

Eg:

```
right_df = right_df.repartition(400)
left_df = left_df.repartition(400) # will lead to one more shuffle when join operation is used down the line
df = left_df.join(right_df, col("id") == col("user_id"), "outter")
```

[image]

```
left_df = left_df.withColumnRenamed("id", "repartition_id").repartition(400, col("repartition_id")
right_df = right_df.withColumnRenamed("user_id", "repartition_id").repartition(400, col("repartition_id")
df = left_df.join(right_df, "repartition_id", "outter")
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, the key that I use to join has an additional column than the partition columns. 
 @Mageswaran

Comment: I don't know the exact case, why you are not considering using all three column for partitioning ?

Comment: The data is already stored in that partition and I don't want to shuffle it.